# Fancybox appears too low on a page with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

My page consists of multiple divs in which the page's content is displayed. Exactly one of these divs is visible at any given time (chosen by select box and hidden/shown in javascript). One of these divs is much taller than the others and it is not the one that appears by default.

Usually the fancybox appears in the center of the page as intended. However, when the tall div is the one currently displayed, a fancybox appears near the bottom of the page. The problem gets worse as the tall div gets taller.

I have tried $.fancybox.center(true); but it had no effect.

I would like to have the fancybox appear in the center of the screen in all cases, but fancybox does not seem to properly interpret the changing height of the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see the code you are using currently? You want the box centered when a page is loaded (at the top then)?

Comment: What I want is to have the fancybox always appear in the middle of the screen. Fancybox seems to make an attempt to do that, but when I make a very tall div show() up with javascript, the fancybox gets confused and posts near the bottom (near what the new half-way point would be).

Comment: My guess? you are setting dimensions (`height`) to either the `html` or `body` tag. If so, try changing it by `min-height` instead